# How to map yoast field with acf field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, yoast

I want to have the yoast fields field get updated when ever a new post is created. 
I have the acf fields i want the content is acf field to be mapped to yoast field,

Please help any ideas will be helping me a lot

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to want the content from ACF to be recognized by the Yoast SEO plug-in? ACF Content Analysis for Yoast SEO does exactly that! https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/acf-content-analysis-for-yoast-seo/

Comment: @imrafaelhi sorry if my question confused you ...i want like when a custom post get published the acf field in the post should update the yoast fields

Comment: Ah sorry, yes. I misunderstood than!